# Get the current refresh token in backend in Django simple-jwt token authentication

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I would like to received the refresh token in backend side to blacklist the token.

I am getting the access token in `request.header` as user pass it in order to call the API, is there any way to get the refresh token while user is not passing in header.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the RefreshToken in this way in views.py:

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.tokens import RefreshToken

def my_request(request):
   token = RefreshToken.for_user([INSERT HERE THE USER CLASS])
   #You can now use the refresh token
   return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```